# Multiple target (large) neural network regression using Python

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, regression

My situation is I have a excel file with 747 nodes (as input) each with a value (imagine 747 columns with floats) and I have an output of 741 values/columns with again floats. These are basically inputs and outputs of a geological simulation. So one row has 747(input)+741(output) =  1488 floats which is one dataset (from one simulation). I have 4 such datasets (rows) to train a neural network such that when I test them on 3 test datasets (747 columns) I get the output of 741 columns. This is just a simple run to get the skeleton of the neural network going before further modifications.

I have come across the Multi-Target Regression example of NYCTaxi (https://github.com/zeahmed/DeepLearningWithMLdotNet/tree/master/NYCTaxiMultiOutputRegression) but I can seem to wrap my head around it.

This is the training set (Input till and including column 'ABS', rest is output):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12TKVbGExt9KcK5RQKTexrToVo8qA5YfeItSaa7E2QdU/edit?usp=sharing

This is the test set:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RjyZsdguucCSOr9QTdTp2ehJBqWCr5yz1-aRjQ_4zo/edit?usp=sharing

This is the test Output (To validate) : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10O_6711CEpJ4DN1w-kCmW01NikjFVZTDmNRuqO3U_6A/edit?usp=sharing

Any guidance/tips would be well appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

We can use an [AutoEncoder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zKuYvjFFS8) for this task. An AutoEncoder takes in the data, compresses it into a latent representation. Now, this representation vector is used to construct the output variable.

So, you can feed the 747-dimensional vector to the model and generate another 747-dimensional vector which is the output. After proper training, the model will be able to generate the target variables for a given set of inputs.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try!